# How to change the axis of Dual axes Graph

Tags: highcharts

How can we change the y axis of each line chart and colum chart .
I attached the sample.I want to change the y axis data of line to right side and change the colum data to left side.
How can we make it possible

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can look into changing the `opposite` property for the axis.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.opposite

Note, for `highstock` the default value is the `opposite` of for `highcharts`
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.opposite